# How to convert string Base64 to pdf in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have successfully sent an attachment from the Java back end to Angular using REST.

I have the result example: JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvclNwYWNlL0

Angular:

```
getImage() {
    this._invoiceCreationHttpService.getImage().subscribe((data: any) => {
      data.forEach(fileUploaded => {
        fetch(fileUploaded.content)
          .then(res => res.blob())
          .then(blob => {
            this.ConvertedBlob = new Blob([fileUploaded.content], {
              type: 'data:application/pdf;base64,'
            });

            console.log(this.ConvertedBlob);
          })
      })
```

I want to show the pdf in my view (html). But the problem is that in the back end I encode InputStream to Base64.getEncoder(). I want to know how to display the pdf as pdf-thumbnail in the front end.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I understood that right, the backend sends back base64 encoded data. So, you have to decode the response data first. The workflow should look like this:

```js
fetch(fileUploaded.content) 
  .then(response => {
    // response.data -> response data base64 encoded
    // decoding the data via atob()
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(response.data).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
    return new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
  })
  .then(blob => {
    // Here is your URL you can use
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // i.e. display the PDF content via iframe
    document.querySelector("iframe").src = url;
  });
```

Further you can read about

- [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)
- [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)

---

Edit:

> if i want to display the pdf result in my html using  . do you have any idea how to do it. thanks in advance

Here is an example how you achieve this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwfdhr

Notes:

- Unfortunately I couldn't make `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` work on stackblitz.com. Maybe you can give it a try in your environment. I didn't try it locally. Instead I used `pdf-viewer` and it just worked out-of-the-box. But I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work with another library, because the workflow has the same principle.
- My solution is based on my previous answer. Since I don't know your code base exactly, I've done things the way I understood your workflow:

  - There is a service called `PdfService` (see pdf.service.ts) I created, which basically fetches and returns the base64 encoded PDF content from GitHub Gist that I just created.
  - In the class `AppComponent` (app.component.ts) the base64 content is decoded and converted to blob and that to a `DOMString` URL (via `URL.createObjectURL`).
  - In app.component.html this URL is simply passed to the library for further processing.

---

Edit 2: The above example does not fit perfectly to Angular way. You should implement the business logic in the services, and keep the controllers as lean as possible.

Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4k63jv

Comment: thanks for your response, i tried atob() not working. this one worked   let content = encodeURIComponent(fileUploaded.content);

Comment: Hm, I don't understand how and why `encodeURIComponent()` worked, since I have no information on the `fetch(fileUploaded.content) ` call. I thought you are fetching the file content from backend with that call, where `fileUploaded.content` is the URL to this file.

Anyway, glad, I could somehow help. :D

Comment: if i want to display the pdf result in my html using <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="" > . do you have any idea how to do it. thanks in advance